# How to find by referenced document in Doctrine ODM with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, dql

I have one document in my "params" collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d124cef3ffcf6f410000037"),
  "code": "color",
  "productTypes": [
    {
      "$ref": "productTypes",
      "$id": ObjectId("4d120a2d2b8d8d3010000000"),
      "$db": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

the referenced document is this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d120a2d2b8d8d3010000000"),
  "code": "car"
}
```

I'm using DoctrineODM to fetch the "param" documents which referenced "productType" is "car". I'm using this code:

```
$query = $dm->createQuery('Cms\Model\Param');
$query->field('productTypes.code')->equals('car');
$result = $query->execute();
var_dump($result);
```

but the result is an empty array. How can i do this?

Comment: What database are you connecting to? It's not 'test' or 'admin' right?

Comment: no. it's not test or admin. i changed the name.

Comment: Can we see your document classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you using ReferenceMany or ReferenceOne you can't query by any reference document field, except reference document id.

If you need query on `code` from referenced collection you should use `EmbedMany` instead of `ReferenceMany`.

In this case your document will be:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d124cef3ffcf6f410000037"),
  "code": "color",
  "productTypes": [
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("4d120a2d2b8d8d3010000000"),
       "code": "car"
     }
  ]
}
```

And following query will work:

```
$query = $dm->createQuery('Cms\Model\Param');
$query->field('productTypes.code')->equals('car');
$result = $query->execute();
var_dump($result);
```

Also if your ProductType code is unique you can use it instead of `MongoId`, in this case you can query on $id:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d124cef3ffcf6f410000037"),
  "code": "color",
  "productTypes": [
    {
      "$ref": "productTypes",
      "$id": 'car',
      "$db": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Referenced document:

```
{
  "_id": 'car'
}
```

Query:

```
$query->field('productTypes.$id')->equals('car');
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. You can't use Embed* for everything- Reference* is there for a reason. The real problem as I see it is that you have to peek into actual DB on your own to realize that references are mapped as $varname.id. So you can query: ...->findBy(array('referenceField.id' => managedDoc->getId()) Still this is definitely not a good solution because one shouldn't care or even know about internal way Doctrine does Reference* associations...

Comment: Actually, I take that back - partially. DocumentPersister->prepareQueryValue() in Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters in DoctrineODM seems to do the magic! It converts 'referenceVar.idField' in the find* queries so that regardless of the underlying implementation of Reference* it will work. I.e. it seems that  findOneBy('referencedDoc.id' -> ...some_id...) is the intended usage...  I am continually amazed at how much work has gone into building Doctrine ODM for Mongo. It's so huge and so well thought out!

Comment: @JakubP. How about adding these comments as an answer.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone wondering in the future... you have to create the index for productTypes.$id within Mongo or else DoctrineODM throws an exception saying there is no index (despite this working in Mongo CLI)

Answer (score 7):

You must use the ***references()*** method of Query Builder for a *@MongoDB\ReferenceOne* like https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

```
$productType = $dm->getRepository('Cms\Model\ProductTypes')->findOneByCode('car');

$queryBuilder = $dm->getRepository('Cms\Model\Param')->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->field('productTypes')->references($productType);

$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

**PS**: use ***includesReferenceTo()*** a *@MongoDB\ReferenceMany*

Answer (score 0):

```
->field('productTypes.code')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*car.*/i'))
```